Flutter web app - FCM not working after reload page
I have a Flutter Web application. In it, I use push notifications. The start screen is the login screen. I have two scenarios:

First launch of the application:
When the user clicks "login", I request permission to receive push notifications - a dialog appears, and I register handlers for notifications.
NotificationSettings result = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();



Currently, everything works fine.

Reloading the page in the browser:
However, when I reload the page in the browser, it doesn't work.
Although the login page opens after reloading, and I click "login".
The same code as in "scenario 1" is executed when clicking. The only difference is that the "permission dialog" does not appear, but that makes sense since I have already granted permission. However, in this case, push notifications do not work.

what could be the reason? how to fix it?

The notification permission message should only be displayed to the user once.
If the user accepts or denies it, the message shouldn't appear again unless the browser cookies are cleared.
